# Syntax error when installing Epson Linux scanner driver (for v550)

Tags: drivers, dpkg, scanner, epson

I have an Epson v550 scanner, and have downloaded the latest official driver file.

http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=perfection-v550&version=2.30.4

When I extract the file, and try to install the `iscan-data` package, I get the following error:

```sh
sudo dpkg -i iscan-data_1.39.1-2_all.deb 
[sudo] password for brylie: 
(Reading database ... 342144 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack iscan-data_1.39.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking iscan-data (1.39.1-2) over (1.39.1-2) ...
Setting up iscan-data (1.39.1-2) ...
expr: syntax error: missing argument after ‘-’
tail: invalid number of lines: ‘/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules’
```

**Note:** I get the same error when running `./install.sh`, it is just related to the `iscan-data` package.

How can I fix the syntax error that is causing the .deb installation to break?

**Edit:**

```
$ dpkg -S /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
libsane:i386, libsane:amd64: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
```

```
$ cat /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
# This file was automatically created based on description files (*.desc)
# by sane-desc 3.5 from sane-backends 1.0.27
#
# udev rules file for supported USB and SCSI devices
#
# For the list of supported USB devices see /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-sane.hwdb
#
# The SCSI device support is very basic and includes only
# scanners that mark themselves as type "scanner" or
# SCSI-scanners from HP and other vendors that are entitled "processor"
# but are treated accordingly.
#
# If your SCSI scanner isn't listed below, you can add it to a new rules
# file under /etc/udev/rules.d/.
#
# If your scanner is supported by some external backend (brother, epkowa,
# hpaio, etc) please ask the author of the backend to provide proper
# device detection support for your OS
#
# If the scanner is supported by sane-backends, please mail the entry to
# the sane-devel mailing list (sane-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org).
#
ACTION!="add", GOTO="libsane_rules_end"

# The following rule will disable USB autosuspend for the device
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{libsane_matched}=="yes", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="on"

SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", GOTO="libsane_scsi_rules_begin"
GOTO="libsane_rules_end"

LABEL="libsane_scsi_rules_begin"
KERNEL!="sg[0-9]*", GOTO="libsane_rules_end"

# Generic: SCSI device type 6 indicates a scanner
ATTRS{type}=="6", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Some scanners advertise themselves as SCSI device type 3

# Wildcard: for some Epson SCSI scanners
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="EPSON", ATTRS{model}=="SCANNER*", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Epson Expression 800 | Epson Expression 800
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="EPSON", ATTRS{model}=="Expression800", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Epson Perfection 2450 | Epson GT-9700F | Epson Perfection 2450 PHOTO
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="EPSON", ATTRS{model}=="GT-9700", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Epson Perfection 3200 | Epson GT-9800F | Epson Perfection 3200 PHOTO
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="EPSON", ATTRS{model}=="GT-9800", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Epson GT-X900 | Epson Perfection V700 Photo | Epson Perfection V750 Photo
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="EPSON", ATTRS{model}=="GT-X900", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Epson Perfection 636S | Epson Perfection 1200S | Epson Perfection 1200S
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="EPSON", ATTRS{model}=="Perfection1200", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Epson Perfection 636 | Epson Perfection 636S
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="EPSON", ATTRS{model}=="Perfection636", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 4p
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="HP", ATTRS{model}=="C1130A", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet IIc
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="HP", ATTRS{model}=="C1750A", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet IIp
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="HP", ATTRS{model}=="C1790A", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet IIcx
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="HP", ATTRS{model}=="C2500A", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 4c
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="HP", ATTRS{model}=="C2520A", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 5p
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="HP", ATTRS{model}=="C5110A", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 6200C
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="HP", ATTRS{model}=="C6270A", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

# Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 6300C
ATTRS{type}=="3", ATTRS{vendor}=="HP", ATTRS{model}=="C7670A", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"


LABEL="libsane_rules_end"
```

Comment: Remember to file a bug with Epson so they fix their deb

Comment: I contacted Epson support via phone and email, but got a boilerplate response: "Please call Linux" from the phone support and "Per Epson's support policy, Epson unfortunately does not provide support for Linux drivers" from email support.

Comment: `dpkg -S /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules` please edit your question for output. And `cat /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules`

Comment: Added the above requested info.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Debian 10 (Buster), and I've found the same problem. The origin of that error is in the file `/usr/lib/iscan-data/make-policy-file`, included in the `iscan-data_1.39.1-2_all.deb` package. It tries to look for the `{idProduct}` string in the `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules` file. But the content of that file has changed substantially between Debian 9 and 10, so it can't find such string and it fails. I guess that also may be occurring in Ubuntu. In spite of that error, the SANE back-end seems to be installed well.

In addition to that problem, I've found one more, also related to the `60-libsane.rules` file: it doesn't contain, anymore, the rule that grants the `scanner` group access to the scanner bus. So I only could scan with the `root` user, from the command line. Check this [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918358) for more information. After adding an *udev* rule similar to the one mentioned in that report, now I can scan again with my user and from a GUI. My rule is as follows:

```
ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="04b8", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0130", RUN+="/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/setfacl -m g:scanner:rw $env{DEVNAME}'"
```

I need to filter by vendor ID and model ID (EPSON Perfection V500 Photo in my case) because the `libsane_matched` property seems to be empty. I guess that it's not properly set because of the problem with the installer mentioned in the 1st paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, this works as a charm! For beginners: this solution assumes that you are in group `scanner` (type `groups` on a terminal window to list the groups you are in). If you are not, enter `sudo adduser --quiet <your_username> scanner` in a terminal window and then log out of the system (or simply reboot). Finally, check the output of the command `groups` again to make sure that you are now a member of the `scanner` group.